# One question on >> c/c++

Tags: c++

No entiendo por qué al introducir `abcd efgh`, en `cadena1[0]` y `cadena1[1]`, no me esta mostrando `a,b`. Otra pregunta, si introduzco `abcdefghij`, ¿por qué no me mete directamente `abc` en el primer array y `def` en el segundo?

```
char cadena1[3];
char cadena2[3];
std::cin>>cadena1;
std::cin>>cadena2;
unsigned int i;
std::cout<<"cadena1"<<std::endl;
for (i = 0;i<sizeof(cadena1);i++)
{
  std::cout<<i;
  std::cout<<cadena1[i]<<std::endl;
}
unsigned int j;
std::cout<<"cadena2"<<std::endl;
for (j = 0;j<sizeof(cadena2);j++)
 {
   std::cout<<j;
   std::cout<<cadena2[j]<<std::endl;
 }
return 0;
}
```

Salida:

```
abcd
efgh
cadena1
0h
1(signo raro)
2c
cadena2
0e
1f
2g
```

---

me sale lo siguiente:[image: erro funcion max() no encontrada la función]: me falta algo?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**.  Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: Debe ser porque  cadena1 y cadena2 no tienen el tamaño suficiente para albergar las cadenas.

Comment: introduce cadena1:abc
introduce cadena2:def , he probado lo que comentas  y en la posicion cero de cadena uno me sigue guardando un caracter extraño.

Comment: Respecto a la edición de la pregunta, mira [este enlace](https://wandbox.org/permlink/F5LRPWsHPbr58jtH)... el uso parece correcto y si falla puede ser por otro motivo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No entiendo por qué al introducir abcd efgh, en cadena1[0] y cadena1[1], no me esta mostrando a,b

En C++ las cadenas de caracteres finalizan con el caracter `'\0'`, es decir, que la cadena `"abc"` se almacenará como `"abc\0"`. Dicho de otra forma, si tu idea es almacenar una cadena de 3 caracteres necesitas un arreglo con capacidad para al menos 4 elementos... si no haces eso desbordarás el arreglo y pisarás memoria de otros procesos.

En tu caso es facil de ver:

```
0h
1(signo raro)
```

Lo que ha sucedido es que `efgh` ha pisado la memoria de `cadena1`:

```
           0x01 0x02 0x03   0x04 0x05 0x06   0x07 0x08
         | cadena2        | cadena1        | otra memoria
abcd  -> |                |  a    b    c   |  d    \0
efgh  -> |  e    f    g   |  h   \0    c   |  d    \0
```

Puedes comprobar que esto es así sacando por pantalla `cadena1` y `cadena2`:

```
std::cout << "cadena1: " << cadena1 << '\n'
          << "cadena2: " << cadena2 << '\n';
```

Se imprimirá lo siguiente:

```
cadena1: h
cadena2: efgh
```

E incluso podemos ir más lejos si modificamos el segundo caracter de `cadena1`:

```
cadena[1] = '#';
```

Entonces la salida cambiará a:

```
cadena1: h#cd
cadena2: efgh#cd
```

Para evitar este problema tienes que garantizar que los arreglos tienen el tamaño suficiente para cubrir tus necesidades:

```
// Podran almacenar hasta 4 caracteres
char cadena1[5];
char cadena2[5];
```

O... puedes optar por usar `std::string`, lo cual programando en C++ tiene todo el sentido del mundo y no te tendrás que preocupar por la longitud de las cadenas introducidas por el usuario

```
std::string cadena1, cadena2;
```

> ¿por qué no me mete directamente abc en el primer array y def en el segundo?

Porque el programa no sabe cuales son tus intenciones y se limita a hacer lo que le pides... cuando tu haces:

```
std::cin >> cadena1;
```

El compilador ve que `cadena1` es de tipo `char*` (un puntero a char) y se limita a almacenar caracteres en ese array hasta que se encuentra con un espacio, un salto de línea o se vacíe el buffer, lo que suceda antes.

Dado que estás usando programación de bajo nivel (`char[]` en vez de `std::string`) es tu responsabilidad el garantizar que no desbordas el buffer.

Comment: Otra pregunta q me trae de cabeza, supongamos

Comment: Si pasamos abcdeef Con width() fijado a cuatro solucionó el problema? Cogerá solo 3 caracteres y meterá \0, quedando en el buffer para la siguiente lectura el resto “deed”. ¿Como puedo saber el tamaño Max del buffer para aplicar ignore?¿ Y el buffer en que parte de memoria se almacena ? ¿No invade memoria de otras variables o funciones? Gracias

Comment: @Jcpardo demasiadas preguntas... planteate formular una pregunta nueva

Comment: Como puedo saber el buffer maximo de lo sistema y así ponerlo en el primer parámetro en del ignore? Y este buffer en q parte de memorias se guarda?

Comment: @Jcpardo incluye la libreria limits y usa `std::numeric_limits <int>::max ()` eso te da el valor máximo que puede contener un`int`

Comment: Perdona la ignorancia . Ese parámetro lo conocía pero no logro ver relación entre buffer y el máximo entero del sistema.

Comment: @Jcpardo si quieres estar absolutamente seguro de que vacias todo el buffer debes usar  `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());`... pero no suele ser necesario ya que es complicado que un usuario acumule en el buffer de entrada 2^31 bytes... pero si quieres ser estricto y meticuloso quizás prefieras usar esta otra versión... a efectos prácticos el resultado tiende a ser el mismo